# Chrome developer tools: Failed to parse CPU profile

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome, v8

I tried to debug the performance of my typescript application, but in the chrome developer tools there are no "real" function names (just generals like Animation time fired, compile code, optimize code, task), but I can't even see one of my own function names. When I run the performance test I can see an error in the console: "Failed to parse CPU profile." I can't even get any search results in google. What is this? If I open a random site that's working, only my app can't show function names in the performance view. I am using the latest version of Google Chrome in Windows 10.

I am using webpack for compiling my typescript, I tried both debug and release builds but it is the same problem. I am not using source maps, but that shouldn't be a requirement for performance view.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Seeing the same trying to profile WebAssembly code.

Comment: Seeing the same. I profiled the same app a few days ago without issues. Tried both normal Chrome (102.0.5005.63) and canary (104.0.5096.0)

Comment: Same for me on Edge 102.0.1245.30. Restarting the tab sometimes fixes it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like this known issue: [crbug.com/1330726](https://crbug.com/1330726)

A fix has been landed yesterday and will (likely) make it to Chrome 102 and 103 soon. Today's Canary (104.0.5100.0) should already have it.

Comment: Yes, in Canary it is working, thank you!